# PHP Error on my website

Tags: php, apache, internal-server-error

I installed Wallpaper Script on my domain but it gives this error on the page :

> The server encountered an internal
>   error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, **[no address given]** and
>   inform them of the time the error
>   occurred, and anything you might have
>   done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Can anyone help? Site is http://hotwallpapers.pk

Comment: that may be an bold assumption, but, maybe ... more information about this error may be available in the server error log?

Comment: Is there any .htacces file resides in Wallpaper script?

Comment: look for `error_log` at the same directory the script is.

Comment: This seems to be the standard error document for a 500 status code.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like an Apache error resulting from a malformed or otherwise invalid `.htaccess` file. I recommend checking your `error.log` file, wherever it resides. `/var/log/httpd/error.log` in some distributions.)

Comment: Yes it has a .htaccess file I don't know how to handle it. Should I delete it?

Comment: After removing .htaccess the error is gone but none of the page is working except home. I think this is mod_rewrite problem